# In how many ways $1000000$ can be expressed as a product of $3$ integers?

Tags: number-theory

In how many ways $1000000$ can be expressed as a product of $3$ integers where each integer is greater than 1? Here $a \times b \times c$, $b \times a \times c...$ are considered to be same.

I've tried many ways. But couldn't solve anyway. 
please help me...

Comment: Show us the ways you've tried.  Then we'll be able to give you relevant advice.

Comment: $3121$ is not a factor of $1000$.  It should be $1000=2^35^3$ and $1000000=2^65^6$

Comment: Sorry..I have made a mistake. It should be $3125$ and $3125 = 5 \times 5 \times 5 \times 5 \times 5$

Comment: Where does $3121$ come from?  That's obvious *not* a factor of $1000000=10^=2^6\cdot5^6$

Comment: $1000000 = 2 \times 2 \times 2 \times 2 \times 2 \times 2 \times 5 \times 5 \times 5 \times 5 \times 5 \times 5$. I tried to find out in how many ways we can create three groups using 2,2,2,2,2,2,5,5,5,5,5,5. But failed to do it.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange community! The quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will help you get the most benefit from your time here.

Comment: You might show us a few of those ways. One of them might have been just one special insight away from a successful solution. At least repeating them might help you organize your thoughts.

Comment: I suggest an easier problem first.  First solve how many ways 10,000 can be written as the product of 2 integers, then how many ways $2^43^4$ can be written as the product of 3 integers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Given number is $2^6\times 5^6$. Any factor of it of the form $2^x\times 5^y$ with both $x,y$ not exceeding 6, possibly zero.

We want  $$2^6\times 5^6= 2^{x_1}\times 5^{y_1}\times 2^{x_2}\times 5^{y_2}\times 2^{x_3}\times 5^{y_3}= 2^{x_1+x_2+x_3}\times 5^{y_1+y_2+y_3}$$

Now it is clear that we have to find $0\le x_i,y_i\le 6$ such that $x_1+x_2+x_3=6 $ and $y_1+y_2+y_3=6$. The number of solutions is the answer. This is not difficult as the problem is only about addition and that too with numbers upto 6.

Comment: $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 6$ can be formed in $7!$ ways. $y_1 + y_2 + y_3 = 6$ can also be formed in $7!$ ways. So the answer is $(7!)^2$. Isn't it?

Comment: @T.A. $x_1+x_2+x_3=6$ will not have $7!$ solutions. It will have $\binom{8}{2}=28$ solutions. *Hint:* stars and bars.

Comment: We also need to discard solutions where $x_1 = y_1 = 0$ (and similarly for the two other pairs of exponents) since the problem statement requires all factors to be greater than $1.$

Comment: Also, stars and bars gives you factors $a\times b\times c$ and $b\times a\times c$ as two different results if $a\neq b.$ The problem statement says these should only count once.

Comment: This answer gives a good starting point, however. Next you can figure out how many times unallowed factorizations were counted and how many times allowed factorizations were overcounted, and subtract all of those.

Answer (score 0):

I get $114$.  Here's how:

Exponents on the three powers of $2$ can be (in ascending order):

*all different*

- $0,1,5$
- $0,2,4$
- $1,2,3$

*two the same*

- $0,0,6$
- $0,3,3$
- $1,1,4$

*all three same*

- $2,2,2$

and likewise for the three powers of $5$.

So for the "all different powers on the $2$s and all different powers on the $5$s" we have:

Example:  pairing $0,1,5$ for $2$s with $0,1,5$ for $5$s:

- $(2^0 5^5) (2^1 5^0) (2^5 5^1)$
- $(2^0 5^0) (2^1 5^5) (2^4 5^1)$
- $(2^0 5^1) (2^1 5^0) (2^4 5^5)$
- etc...

But... as pointed out by @farruhota, the calculation includes cases where there is a factor of $1$ (i.e., $2^0 5^0)$ so we do not include those.

Go through all such cases and find $114$.

Here's a list:

{{2, 2, 250000}, {2, 4, 125000}, {2, 5, 100000}, {2, 8, 62500}, {2, 
  10, 50000}, {2, 16, 31250}, {2, 20, 25000}, {2, 25, 20000}, {2, 32, 
  15625}, {2, 40, 12500}, {2, 50, 10000}, {2, 80, 6250}, {2, 100, 
  5000}, {2, 125, 4000}, {2, 160, 3125}, {2, 200, 2500}, {2, 250, 
  2000}, {2, 400, 1250}, {2, 500, 1000}, {2, 625, 800}, {4, 4, 
  62500}, {4, 5, 50000}, {4, 8, 31250}, {4, 10, 25000}, {4, 16, 
  15625}, {4, 20, 12500}, {4, 25, 10000}, {4, 40, 6250}, {4, 50, 
  5000}, {4, 80, 3125}, {4, 100, 2500}, {4, 125, 2000}, {4, 200, 
  1250}, {4, 250, 1000}, {4, 400, 625}, {4, 500, 500}, {5, 5, 
  40000}, {5, 8, 25000}, {5, 10, 20000}, {5, 16, 12500}, {5, 20, 
  10000}, {5, 25, 8000}, {5, 32, 6250}, {5, 40, 5000}, {5, 50, 
  4000}, {5, 64, 3125}, {5, 80, 2500}, {5, 100, 2000}, {5, 125, 
  1600}, {5, 160, 1250}, {5, 200, 1000}, {5, 250, 800}, {5, 320, 
  625}, {5, 400, 500}, {8, 8, 15625}, {8, 10, 12500}, {8, 20, 
  6250}, {8, 25, 5000}, {8, 40, 3125}, {8, 50, 2500}, {8, 100, 
  1250}, {8, 125, 1000}, {8, 200, 625}, {8, 250, 500}, {10, 10, 
  10000}, {10, 16, 6250}, {10, 20, 5000}, {10, 25, 4000}, {10, 32, 
  3125}, {10, 40, 2500}, {10, 50, 2000}, {10, 80, 1250}, {10, 100, 
  1000}, {10, 125, 800}, {10, 160, 625}, {10, 200, 500}, {10, 250, 
  400}, {16, 20, 3125}, {16, 25, 2500}, {16, 50, 1250}, {16, 100, 
  625}, {16, 125, 500}, {16, 250, 250}, {20, 20, 2500}, {20, 25, 
  2000}, {20, 40, 1250}, {20, 50, 1000}, {20, 80, 625}, {20, 100, 
  500}, {20, 125, 400}, {20, 200, 250}, {25, 25, 1600}, {25, 32, 
  1250}, {25, 40, 1000}, {25, 50, 800}, {25, 64, 625}, {25, 80, 
  500}, {25, 100, 400}, {25, 125, 320}, {25, 160, 250}, {25, 200, 
  200}, {32, 50, 625}, {32, 125, 250}, {40, 40, 625}, {40, 50, 
  500}, {40, 100, 250}, {40, 125, 200}, {50, 50, 400}, {50, 80, 
  250}, {50, 100, 200}, {50, 125, 160}, {64, 125, 125}, {80, 100, 
  125}, {100, 100, 100}}

Comment: But the choices with $(2^05^0)$ must be ignored, because by requirement each integer must be greater than $1$.

Answer (score 0):

There are seven ascending partitions $(006)$–$(222)$ of $6$ into three $\geq0$ parts. We have to choose such a partition for the three exponents $x_1\leq x_2\leq x_3$ of $2$ and independently a partition for the three exponents $y_j$ of $5$. For each of the $49$ possible combinations we have to find out how many different factor triples we can form by permuting the entries of the chosen $y_j$-partition. If I have done this correctly I obtain the following (symmetric) table, whereby the rows are corresponding to the $(x_1x_2x_3)$ and the columns to the $(y_1y_2y_3)$:

$$\matrix{
&006&015&024&033&114&123&222\cr
\cr
006:\quad &0&1&1&1&2&3&1\cr
015:\quad&1&4&4&2&3&6&1\cr
024:\quad&1&4&4&2&3&6&1\cr
033:\quad&1&2&2&1&2&3&1\cr
114:\quad&2&3&3&2&2&3&1\cr
123:\quad&3&6&6&3&3&6&1\cr
222:\quad&1&1&1&1&1&1&1\cr}$$
Adding all entries in this table gives $114$.

Comment: OP said the order of factors does not matter

Comment: I see, I was counting a factor of $1$.  So far so good, then.

Comment: @RossMillikan: In my counting the order does not matter. The pairing $(114, 015)$ means that we have $2^1 5^{y_1}\cdot 2^1 5^{y_2}\cdot2^4 5^{y_3}$ with $\{y_1,y_2,y_3\}=\{0,1,5\}$.